# SQL Server : condition to check the Employees who does not have a particular role and do not have another role

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `dbo.[Employee]` and `dbo.[EmployeeRole]`, I need to get all the `[EmployeeId]` from `dbo.[Employee]` table whose `[EmployeeTypeId] = 1` and the condition is these EmployeeId's must also be present in the `dbo.[EmployeeRole]` table with only `RoleId = 5` AND they should not have `RoleId = 6`.

In short the EmployeeId's which I am going to fetch from the `dbo.[Employee]` table should have a record with `RoleId = 5` in the `dbo.[EmployeeRole]` table and they should not have an entry with `RoleId = 6`.

Note: each `EmployeeId` can have multiple roles in `dbo.[EmployeeRole]` table

```
SELECT [EmployeeId] 
FROM dbo.[Employee] 
WHERE [EmployeeTypeId] = 1 
  AND EmployeeId IN (SELECT [EmployeeId] 
                     FROM dbo.[EmployeeRole] 
                     WHERE [EmployeeRoleId] = 5)
```

I could not add a condition where I need to check that the user does not have a record with `[RoleId] = 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several permutations for this exist, coincidentally `exists` is one method;

```
Select EmployeeId
from Employees e 
where exists (select * from EmployeeRole r where r.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId and r.RoleId=5)
and not exists (select * from EmployeeRole r where r.EmployeeId=e.EmployeeId and r.RoleId=6)
where e.EmployeeTypeId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first select `EmployeeId`s with `EmployeeRoleId =5` and use `NOT EXISTS` to filter out the `EmployeeId`s who also has`EmployeeRoleId =6`

Updated the Query.

```
SELECT [EmployeeId] 
FROM dbo.[Employee] E 
WHERE [EmployeeTypeId] = 1 
AND [EmployeeRoleId]  IN (SELECT [EmployeeId] 
 FROM dbo.[EmployeeRole]
 WHERE  [EmployeeRoleId] = 5)
AND NOT EXISTS
( 
 SELECT [EmployeeId] 
 FROM dbo.[EmployeeRole] ER 
 WHERE ER.[EmployeeId] = E.[EmployeeId]
 AND [EmployeeRoleId] = 6
 )
```

Comment: The [EmployeeRoleId] is not part of Employee Table, when i execute the query it says invalid column name 'EmployeeRoleId'

Answer (score 0):

It's not that complicated, You can first select EmployeeIds with EmployeeRoleId =5 and select the hasEmployeeRoleId who they are different than 6 using "not exist"

```
select [EmployeeId] from dbo.[Employee] as emp
 where [EmployeeTypeId] = 1 and [EmployeeRoleId] = 5
and not exist( select[EmployeeId] from dbo.[EmployeeRole] as emprole 
and emprole.[EmployeeId] = emp.[EmployeeId]
 and [EmployeeRoleId] = 6);
go
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.EmployeeId
FROM dbo.Employee as e INNER JOIN dbo.EmployeeRole as er
    ON er.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
WHERE e.EmployeeTypeId = 1 
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN er.EmployeeRoleId = 5 THEN 1 END) = 1
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN er.EmployeeRoleId = 6 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Comment: It is not EmployeeId, it is EmployeeRoleId, there is no join with [EmployeeRole] table in your query

Comment: @ncsql Yup, I did fail to notice that the join wasn't in your query that I pasted here. Easy to fix by adding that join. The key point is to notice everything beginning with the `group by`